# xacro prase the value from YAML by giving variable

Tags: xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Environment: ROS Noetic, Gazebo11

I try to use xacro with YAML, but there is a problem about argument of variable:

My yaml:

```
---
  color_0: "1 1 1 1.0"
  color_1: "0 0 0 1.0"
  color_2: "0.84 0 0 1.0"
  color_3: "0.55 0.24 1 1.0"
  color_4: "0.01 0.53 0 1.0"
```

Because I want to use different value at different time.

So I tried to load the value as below:

```
  <xacro:property name="YAML_FILE" value="$(find gazebo_ros_model_color)/configs/colors.yaml" />
  <xacro:property name="COLORS" value="${load_yaml(YAML_FILE)}"/>

  <xacro:arg name="color" default="color_0" />  <!-- need to use variable -->
  <color>${COLORS[${color}]}</color>
```

But it cause the ERROR :((

```
...
invalid expression: ${color 
when evaluating expression 'COLORS['${color'
...
```

Is it possible to get the value from YAML by key variable given?

Any suggestion is welcome

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385205/xacro-prase-the-value-from-yaml-by-giving-variable/) by [NEET](https://answers.ros.org/users/41884/neet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The different use of `xacro:property`, `xacro:arg`, and `xacro:params` is:

`xacro:arg` is use `$(arg VAR)`.
`xacro:property` and `xacro:params` are use `${VAR}`

So, I solve my problem as below:

```
<xacro:arg name="color" default="color_${id_num}" />
<color>${COLORS['$(arg color)']}</color>
```

And I also tried to use xacro:property, but CAN NOT use it like:

```
<xacro:property name="color" value="color_0" />
<color>${COLORS['${color}']}</color>
```

---

Originally posted by [NEET](https://answers.ros.org/users/41884/neet/) with karma: 13 on 2021-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @NEET,

My XML File: colors.yaml

```
  color_0: "1 1 1 1.0"
  color_1: "0 0 0 1.0"
  color_2: "0.84 0 0 1.0"
  color_3: "0.55 0.24 1 1.0"
  color_4: "0.01 0.53 0 1.0"
```

For accessing Yaml file data,

```
<xacro:property name="properties" value="${load_yaml(package + '/<path>/colors.yaml')}"/>
<xacro:property name="color_0" value="${properties['color_0']}"/>
```

OR You can also load Yaml file like this way,

```
<xacro:property name="properties" value="${load_yaml($(find package)/filename.yaml)}"/>
```

I hope It will work, If you having any issues feel free to drop a comment.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-08-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEET](https://answers.ros.org/users/41884/neet/) on 2021-08-26**:
Sorry...I didn't express the problem well.
I need to pass another variable as key like ${properties[${var}]. because I want to pass the key that I want.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-08-26**:
${var} Can you please! explain this? How you are entering this?
thanks

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-08-26**:
Just to Note:

If you are having a variable let's say: M_body and its value is color_0.

```
<xacro:property name="M_body" value="color_0"/>
```

And do you want to access this value and you want to pass:

```
<xacro:property name="properties" value="${load_yaml(package + '/<path>/colors.yaml')}"/>

<xacro:property name="color_0" value="${properties[M_body]}"/>
```

I without " "  -> I think it will work.

**Comment by [NEET](https://answers.ros.org/users/41884/neet/) on 2021-08-26**:
Hi, I found the different between xacro property and arg

And I solve my problem like:

```
<xacro:arg name="color" default="color_${id_num}" />
<color>${COLORS['$(arg color)']}</color>
```

Thank you for your reply
Really grateful

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-08-26**:
Can you please! post your solution as an answer and Tick your solution. It can help others.

**Comment by [NEET](https://answers.ros.org/users/41884/neet/) on 2021-08-26**:
Yes, I posted my answer. Any advice is welcome. Thanks again :)